# Delphi, Indy10, How to properly stop and cleanup a readln on a continuous stream

Tags: delphi, indy, server-sent-events

Using Delphi 2010 and Indy10

I am attempting to read Server Sent Events from Delphi. I have managed to create a thread which will subscribe to a connection on my server (Python/Flask) and capture the events. A thread is needed because the HTTP.Get is blocking forever. I realize that the entire protocol is not implemented, but I am only interested in receiving short strings broadcast from the server. The following code works, however I have not been able to figure out how to cleanly stop the thread and free the http_client and stream when stopping my program.

On the server side I get ""An existing connection was forcibly close by the remote host"" and my program is indicating memory leaks. I have tried many different combinations of trying to close the http connection at various points (onTerminate,Destroy) and I can't get anything to work. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant code I have so far:

```
TSSEThread = class(TThread)
   private
     url: String;
     stream: TMemoryStream;
     http_client: TidHTTP;
     procedure DoOnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
   public
     constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; url: String);
     procedure Execute; override;
end;


constructor TSSEThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; url: String);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended); // sending False here
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  Self.url := url;
end;

procedure TSSEThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  try
    stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    http_client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    http_client.OnWork := DoOnWork;
    http_client.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    http_client.Request.Accept := 'text/event-stream';
    http_client.Response.KeepAlive := True;
    while not Terminated do
      try
        http_client.Get(self.url,stream);
      except
        on E: Exception do begin
          try
            http_client.Disconnect;
          except
          end;
          if http_client.IOHandler <> nil then http_client.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
          sleep(3000);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      http_client.Free;
      stream.Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TSSEThread.DoOnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  msg: string;
begin
  if self.Terminated then Exit;
  SetString(msg,PAnsiChar(stream.Memory),stream.Size);
  stream.Position := 0;
  if Pos('data:',msg) > 0 then
  begin
    // Handle msg here. This works fine.
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnWork` event handler, when the thread's `Terminated` property is true, raise an exception (such as by calling `SysUtils.Abort()`) instead of calling `Exit`.  That exception will abort the HTTP request and close the connection, then propegate to `Execute()`, where you catch it and check `Terminated` again to break your `while` loop and let your `finally` block free the `TIdHTTP` object before exiting `Execute()` to terminate the thread.

```
procedure TSSEThread.DoOnWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  msg: string;
begin
  //if self.Terminated then Exit;
  if self.Terminated then SysUtils.Abort;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. That works if I mark my thread as terminated, then publish an event to trigger the OnWork handler. My normal events can be minutes apart. Is there a way to trigger OnWork without having to send a new event through the server?

Comment: No, because obviously there is no work being done during that time frame. What you really should be doing instead is not let `TIdHTTP` block for such long periods of time to begin with. Read the events yourself instead so that you can stop and check your thread's `Terminated` periodically. For instance, if your server events are using `multipart/x-mixed-replace` then you can enable the [`hoNoReadMultipartMIME` flag](http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20140305.aspx) in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property (upgrade to the latest Indy version if you have not done so yet).

Comment: If that is not an option, then you may have to switch to using `TIdTCPClient` directly instead, and then send your own HTTP request so that you can handle all of the reading in your own code.

Comment: Thanks Again! By adding http_client.ReadTimeout := 1000; The connection will remain, but the DoOnWork will get called at least every second. That should take care of it.

Comment: `OnWork` is triggered only when actual data is sent/received. `TIdHTTP` has no internal timer like you are suggesting. If you set a read timeout and no data arrives within that timeout period, an `EIdReadTimeout` exception is raised.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau: aren't there any non-kludgey solutions? With raw OS calls I'd have the thread sleep on an array containing a byebye event in addition to the sockets, no polling needed. I'd be suprised if Indy didn't have something similar instead of resorting to polling. But I'm very new to Indy and at the moment I see only a huge mountain of classes, functions and constants (i.e. I can't see the forest for the trees)...

Comment: @DarthGizka: No, there is nothing like that in Indy. It uses blocking socket I/O (see [Introduction to Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/IntroIndy.html)). What you are suggesting requires asynchronous I/O instead, so the socket and event states can be monitored at the same time. While Indy is in the middle of an I/O operation, the calling thread is blocked, so there is no option to monitor an event except by polling, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau:I was thinking of things like TIdAntiFreeze where the 'blocking read' simply refers to the semantics of the function called by the user but things are different under the hood. 'Pure' blocking calls (i.e. where the OS does the waiting on the socket and not the framework) are just too problematic for production-grade code. I.e. no way for closing the connection gracefully, things like that. OTOH, we have some clients who have never closed a connection gracefully, and I know they paid big $$$ for their software. Perhaps I'm mistaken in my conception of 'production-grade code'...

Comment: @DarthGizka: TIdAntiFreeze only works in the main UI thread, and is used to keep the message queue pumping while Indy is performing socket I/O operations that block the main thread. Indy does use "pure blocking calls", letting the OS wait on the socket. There is nothing wrong with doing that in production code (many platforms do not even support non-blocking/asynchronous socket I/O). And yes, there are ways to close sockets gracefully (in fact, my answer above shows one way to do it)